# Reduce the size of Very Large Excel Data Model

Tags: powerpivot

Hi I created a data model with 295K rows and 27 columns which comes out to be 17 MB when i ran a power pivot table. After adding another table with 227K row to the data model all sudden data size jumps to over 42 mb? Can anyone advise me on how to reduce the size of the data model...

Thanks

Comment: What is the source of the 500k rows? A database table? Or a sheet in that Excel workbook?

Comment: It's an excel database table that feeds of a excel dashboard

Comment: Is the source a sheet in the same Excel file or a separate? (I don't know what "excel database table" means. Is it an excel sheet or a database?)

Comment: Its a separe excel file. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options. For reference I would recommend reading [this article](https://www.powerpivotpro.com/2015/12/compression-with-power-pivot/) which discusses PowerPivot's compression techniques.

1. Powerpivot is more about the columns than the rows. The fewer distinct values you have in your columns, the better. So can you roll-up some of your dimensions or get rid of some columns BEFORE importing the data?
2. Reduce rows by aggregating your data. Do you really need that much detail, for 275K rows, in order to run your analysis? You'd be surprised if you take a critical look, how little you might need.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately there is no room to reduce the number of columns in the data set. But i figured out a way around it by running pivot table off cache.